# Upload images to Google Cloud Endpoints with a form

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to upload an Image with a form to a enpoints api. The upload and the saving to google cloud storage seems to be working.

[image]

But if I click on the image in the developer console, it only shows a 16x16px empty image and not the original image.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form action="https://xyz.appspot.com/_ah/api/undergogo/v1/image" 
 target="_blank" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data" 
 method="post" 
 onchange="readImage();">

  <input type="text" name="desc"/>
  <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="imgFile"/>
  <input id="fileInputBase64" type="hiden" name="img" />
  <input type="submit" value="upload">

</form>
```

Encode to base64 and save string in the hidden field fileInputBase64.

```
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Get elem by ID

function readImage() {
    if ( el("fileInput") && el("fileInput").files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
             el("fileInputBase64").value = e.target.result;
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( el("fileInput").files[0] );
    }
}
```

API

```
@endpoints.method(ImageMessage, Status,
                path='image', http_method='POST',
                name='image.upload')
def image_upload(self, request):
  my_default_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(initial_delay=0.2,
                                      max_delay=5.0,
                                      backoff_factor=2,
                                      max_retry_period=15)

  bucket_name = os.environ.get('xyz.appspot.com',app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
  bucket = '/' + bucket_name

  filename = bucket + '/demo-image2o.jpg'
  self.tmp_filenames_to_clean_up = []

  # write file
  gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                'w',
                 content_type='image/jpeg')

  gcs_file.write(request.img.decode('base64'))
  gcs_file.close()
  self.tmp_filenames_to_clean_up.append(filename)

  return Status(code=0,message=request.desc)
```

ImageMessage class:

```
class ImageMessage(messages.Message):
  url     = messages.StringField(1)
  desc    = messages.StringField(2)
  img     = messages.BytesField(3)
```